# Sent table from Azure SQL to snowflake

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-sql-database

I would like to configure sending data from azure SQL database to Snowflake (And also, as an option to send in the future only changes in the database, not the whole database).

I have created logical templates in Logical app and added connectors. But I can't understand how to create sending of the table that I need - "Events" into Snowflake.

Is it possible to do this in Logicall App?
[image]

Connector options in Snowflake
[image]

Comment: you can use ADF to transfer the data from sql to snowflake

Comment: Logicall App you can't pass data to snowflake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to do this in Logicall App?

The logic app connector provides only 4 actions to perform on snowflake.

- Cancel the Execution of a Statement
- Check the Status of the Execution of a Statement and Get the Results
- Convert result set rows from array to objects
- Submit a SQL Statement for Execution

> I would like to configure sending data from azure SQL database to Snowflake.

As you want to sed data from Azure SQL database to Snowflake and the incremented data load you can consider the other services like ADF.

you can follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-snowflake?tabs=data-factory) to transfer data from Azure SQL database to Snowflake and for incremental data load (in the future only changes in the database, not the whole database) check out this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-portal)